React Native android build: error: duplicate class: com.facebook.react.PackageList
I get the error: "duplicate class: com.facebook.react.PackageList" when trying to build my React Native app (0.72.17) for android.
This class can indeed be found in two locations:
/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java
and
/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java
So it's in the 'autolinking' folder and the 'rncli' one.
The error message doesn't say anything more than what I posted above, so it isn't of much help.
This is my android/app/build.gradle file:
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

/**
* This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */

react {
    /* Only comments here */ 
}
/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.hallonewyorkrn"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hallonewyorkrn"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0.3"
    }
    signingConfigs {
            debug {
                storeFile file('debug.keystore')
                storePassword 'android'
                keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
                keyPassword 'android'
            }
            release {
                if (project.hasProperty('ENV_VAR')) {
                    storeFile file(ENV_VAR_FILE)
                    storePassword ENV_VAR_PASS
                    keyAlias ENV_VAR_ALIAS
                    keyPassword ENV_VAR_KEY_PASSWORD
                }
            }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            pickFirsts += ['lib/x86/libc++_shared.so', 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so', 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so', 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so', 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so', 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so']
        }
    }
    
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0"
    implementation project(':react-native-video')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-inappbrowser-reborn')
}
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-image/strip_svgs.gradle"

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
``


If you haven't wrote any native code in your android folder I recommend try
deleting the android folder and run
npx expo prebuild

This should bring back the android and ios folder, then try running the app again.
Use this expo link for reference

Thanks for the comment. I'm not using expo so that's not possible.

Oh I'm sorry, I hope you found your solution. May I know any specific reason that you are not using Expo?
